# How to use scope on many to many relationship correctly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

**table structures**

members

- id
- name

sports

- id
- name

member_sport

- id
- member_id
- sport_id
- is_activated

app/Member.php

```php
public function sports()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Sport::class);
}
```

app/Sport.php

```php
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class)
}
```

if I want to filter the sport which was activated, it's like

`Member::find(1)->sports()->wherePivot('is_activated, true')->get();`

but I want to use scope on it, the result should like

`Member::find(1)->sports()->activated()->get();`

I know I can add something in `app/Sport`

```
public function scopeActivated($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_activated', true);
}
```

but it works due to blurry searching, if I add a column named `is_activated` either in members or sports MySQL  will output

`'is_activated' in where clause is ambiguous`

where should I put the scope to make it right

Comment: try adding table name as prefix in the where condition because if both table has same column it can't determine which one you meant. i.e: `wherePivot('member_sport.is_activated')`

Comment: I've tried it, it will work,  but I thought it is a workaround